# Ruby on Rails: params[] Variable in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby (and Rails), so apologies for the basic question.

As I understand it, the `params[...]` variable inside of my controller is supposed to hold data from the form I've just submitted on my web page? I'm trying to use the following code to update a model depending on whether or not a field is blank:

```
@s3_destination = S3Destination.find(params[:id])

if params[:credentials_secret].to_s.empty?

    update = @s3_destination.update_attributes({
         :name => params[:name],
         :bucket => params[:bucket],
         :region => params[:region],
         :credentials_id => params[:credentials_id]
    })

    if update
        redirect_to @s3_destination
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

else

    update = @s3_destination.update_attributes({
         :name => params[:name],
         :bucket => params[:bucket],
         :region => params[:region],
         :credentials_id => params[:credentials_id],
         :credentials_secret => params[:credentials_secret],
    })

    if update
        redirect_to @s3_destination
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

end
```

The controller action executes fine, but there is now no data in the model, so I'm assuming i'm doing something wrong when setting it in the update_attributes function.

Shouldn't `params[:name]` take the value from the form element with the name "name"? Or have I misunderstood its purpose?

**Edit**

To answer some questions:

I believe this is the relevant log entry, it all looks OK to me?

```
Started PATCH "/s3_destinations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-09 12:40:51 +0000
Processing by S3DestinationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"a26uTf4+58v/O+pTqOYn0R7cjzGVWBnbFVdJ1OWwNnybEpUdYt2FNruOla/ikOnAFLpY3mn71Wow5oVee+R3Ng==", "s3_destination"=>{"name"=>"Cogative Bucket 1", "bucket"=>"cogative-backup-01", "region"=>"eu-west-1", "credentials_id"=>"AKIAIZG2HJ35NR3DQYGA", "credentials_secret"=>"12345"}, "commit"=>"Save S3 destination", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  S3Destination Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "s3_destinations".* FROM "s3_destinations" WHERE "s3_destinations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/s3_destinations/1
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

The form itself is generated like this:

```
<h2>Editing AWS S3 Destination</h2>

<%= form_for :s3_destination, url: s3_destination_path(@s3_destination), method: :patch do |f| %>

    <% if @s3_destination.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@s3_destination.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this source from being saved:
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <% @s3_destination.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <%end %>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :bucket %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :bucket %>
    </p>

    <select name="s3_destination[region]">
      <option value="us-east-1">US Standard (N. Virginia)</option>
      <option value="us-west-2">US West (Oregon)</option>
      <option value="us-west-1">US West (N. California)</option>
      <option value="eu-west-1">EU (Ireland)</option>
      <option value="eu-central-1">EU (Frankfurt)</option>
      <option value="ap-southeast-1">Asia Pacific (Singapore)</option>
      <option value="ap-southeast-2">Asia Pacific (Sydney)</option>
      <option value="ap-northeast-1">Asia Pacific (Tokyo)</option>
      <option value="sa-east-1">South America (Sao Paulo)</option>
    </select>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :credentials_id %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :credentials_id %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :credentials_secret %><br>
      <%= f.password_field :credentials_secret %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You understood correctly, but please show what log says about `Parameters: {...}` for your request

Comment: Which Rails version you are using?

Comment: _Sidenote_: use banged version of `update_attributes!`—it will throw an exception rather than silently return `false` on any error.

Comment: How do you generate the form? Using the Rails form helper for example results in nested params: something like `params[:uploader][:name]` (where `:uploader` depends on your models class.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for the tip, I've changed to using that version! To others, I've added the log file entry and the form itself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems your params are in nested hash, so you have to address them as `params[: s3_destination][...]`, like `params[: s3_destination][...][:name]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `params[:name]`, but the parameters are all bundled up together under `params[:s3_destination]`, so you need to reference `params[:s3_destination][:name]`, etc.

The nice thing about this is you don't need to call out each attribute you want to update. In simple cases, you can just

```
@s3_destination.update_attributes(params[:s3_destination])
```

For safety (eg, so I can't edit the form to submit attributes you don't want me editing), you should use [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters):

```
s3_params = params.require(:s3_destination)
  .permit(:name, :bucket, :region, :credentials_id, :credentials_secret)
@s3_destination.update_attributes(s3_params)
```

And then for your `credentials_secret` logic, you can just delete the blank value from this hash:

```
s3_params = params.require(:s3_destination)
  .permit(:name, :bucket, :region, :credentials_id, :credentials_secret)
s3_params.delete(:credentials_secret) if s3_params[:credentials_secret].blank?
@s3_destination.update_attributes(s3_params)
```

[`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) will catch both `nil` and `""` the way you're currently doing with `.to_s.empty?`.

Comment: Ahah! Thanks for the information! I was using strong parameters before but didn't know how to make it exclude certain values.